# Applying for a visit visa for an elderly parent

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens

My mum always applies for a multiple-visa entry successfully from Nigeria. She has never had any problems coming into the country and going back except for the last visit in 2014.

She missed her flight from Nigeria and had to come in on another flight the next day. However, this, I suspect, drew suspicion to her. She was stopped, interrogated and searched for a long time at Heathrow airport.

Some prescriptions that she was once given on previous trip by her GP from England were seen and queried. Also, I think she was challenged by having overstayed on segments of the multiple entries in the past as well.

She was eventually allowed in for about 3 months, and given a set time to leave the UK. She left in the given timeframe and has not had the confidence to apply for a visit visa since then. This is also coupled with the fact that she is getting on in age and I think she is dreading the complexities of the process of the visa application in her home country.

How do I apply for a visiting visa for her from here in the UK? I am the eldest of four children, and we all reside here. My father is long deceased and my mother is alone in Nigeria. She has a lot of ties in Nigeria and will not come to stay but to visit her children and grandchildren. I am in full-time employment and mum is financially stable. Do you think it should be a straightforward application process?

Comment: Had she overstayed prevously or not? How did she come to have a GP in England?

Comment: It seems unlikely that arriving on a flight one day later than proposed drew attention - more likely that it was the frequency/length of visits and the apparent use of GP services. You can complete the online application on her behalf and send it to her along with any relevant supporting papers, however she’ll need to attend a local biometric appointment

Answer (score 1):

Overall, it appears that immigration officials felt that your mother was attempting to live in the UK through frequent and/or extended visits. They took into account her immigration record of entries and exits, and any violations of visa conditions (e.g., overstay, accessing health care). It's contradictory to suggest that home ties are convincing when, as you say, she is widowed, alone in Nigeria, and all of her children (and grandchildren) live in the UK.

Four years on, what to do? On her last entry in 2014, as she was granted limited leave to enter, a written notice specifying how long and other conditions. Look at those conditions, if any, and decide whether the [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) is again suitable. An Entry Clearance Office would likely consider her immigration record in making a decision and, while her record would still be a factor, a [Family visa](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/family-visas) may be more apt (and an ECO may view that as an appropriate direction).

Before going forward, you may want to seek the guidance of an immigration advisor or practitioner. The UK regulates and registers those legally able to give immigration advice and services (advisers, solicitors, barristers and members of approved professional bodies). Here are some resources:

- [Office of Immigration Services Commissioner](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa)
- [Immigration Law Practitioners' Association](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/)
- [UK Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk)
- [Citizens Advice Bureau](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/)